# iOS Load local image in resources, and show it in <img src='%@'>

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I want to load local resources image in iOS, but failed to show in app (but when I NSLog the link is already shown).
This is my code

```
NSBundle* myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString* imgurl = [myBundle pathForResource:@"list-gotit" ofType:@"png"];

htmltext = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><img src='%@'></html>",
                imgurl];

[self.postview loadHTMLString:htmltext baseURL:baseurl];
```

img src will load my data/ my url is already right i think ( i use NSLOG ) :

```
<img src='/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/66B9184B-796E-4404-B436-E387asd123132/NEWBIE.app/list-gotit.png'>
```

but not show as an image.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

This is working for me:

```
 NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"list-gotit" ofType:@"png"];
 NSURL    *imageURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
 NSString *absoluteURLString = [imageURL absoluteString];
 [html appendFormat:@"<img src=\"%@\" />", absoluteURLString];
```

Or as two liner:

```
NSString *imageURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"list-gotit" ofType:@"png"]] absoluteString];
[html appendFormat:@"<img src=\"%@\" />", imageURL];
```

Comment: i cant do that, show an error    'absoluteString is expected :'

Comment: Sorry, it had a missing bracket. I edited my answer.

Comment: it show an url but not show as an image
<img src='file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/08D55376-6930-4D23-B7B5-C2F123d15681/newbie.app/list-gotit.png' />

Comment: It's not `NSString *imageURL`, it's `NSURL *imageURL`

Comment: No, its not. You have missed the `absoluteString` call. (Which returns a `NSString` object)

Comment: @yogie1989: Maybe you should use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'`. @karthik: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: @yogie1989 I agree with Sebastian Keller the answer he was posted is correct +1.

Comment: All this process only for `file://`?

Comment: Yep, or do you have a better one? I'm always open for new ideas

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a `/` in `<img src="xxxxx" />`

And

```
NSURL *imgUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[myBundle pathForResource:@"list-gotit" ofType:@"png"]];
```

I did a test:

```
NSBundle* myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL *imgUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[myBundle pathForResource:@"list-gotit" ofType:@"png"]];

NSString *htmltext = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><img src='%@'></html>",
            imgUrl];

self.postview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 300)];
[self.view addSubview:self.postview];
[self.postview loadHTMLString:htmltext baseURL:nil];
```

Everything is OK.

Comment: sorry, im already do that but not show an image too only the link of path image

Comment: same, it not show as an image, but the link is already right
<img src='file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/08D55376-6930-4D23-B7B5-C1231231235681/newbie.app/list-gotit.png' />

Answer (score 0):

you just have to change below code.

```
htmltext = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><img src=\"%@\"></html>",
                imgurl];
```

That's it because of '%@' your code is not working use \"%@\" may be help you.